# How can I construct a unique_ptr pointing to a vector with single element conveniently?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization-list

I would like to construct a `unique_ptr` holding a `vector<string>`, which contains single element only. Is it possible to do this in single line of code?
I try this approach:

```
auto values = make_unique<vector<string>>({value});
```

But compiler (clang++) complains:

```
No matching function for call to 'make_unique' candidate template ignored: 
substitution failure [with _Tp = std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >]: no type named '__unique_array_unknown_bound' in 'std::__1::__unique_if<st... candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Tp = std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >]: no type named '__unique_array_known_bound' in 'std::__1::__unique_if<std:... candidate function [with _Tp = std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >, _Args = <>] not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work since `vector` apparently accepts using `initializer_list` for construction.

```
string value = ...;
auto values = vector<string>({value}); // this works
```

Is creating a `unique_ptr<vector<string>>` and calling its `push_back` the only viable approach for constructing such a `unique_ptr`?

```
auto values = make_unique<vector<string>>();
values->push_back(value);
```

More broadly, if I have a fixed number of elements (for example, 3 elements), and would like to build a `unique_ptr` holding a vector with these elements, what is the idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: Side question: Why would you allocate the vector dynamically?

Comment: @eerorika for "allocate the vector dynamically", do you mean why do I prefer the coding style above? Probably because I am a Java programmer previously and get used to the `Arrays.asList("1","2","3")` coding style, and I feel that is a more concise way to express my intension that only fix number of elements are there.

Comment: I don't quite get how asList is related to dynamic allocation of the vector. Being a Java developer may be the reason, since there everything is allocated dynamically. As a hint: You can make your program faster by avoiding unnecessary dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{...}` appearing in a function call is not an initializer list (unless the function explicitly asks for a `std::initializer_list`); it's only an initializer list if it's being used to directly initialize something (e.g. on the right-hand-side of an assignment, or in a range-for loop).

If you really want to pass an initializer list, you can do so explicitly:

```cpp
auto values = std::make_unique<std::vector<std::string>>(
  std::initializer_list<std::string>{ value });
```

You could also just construct a temporary vector and pass that in instead:

```cpp
auto values = std::make_unique<std::vector<std::string>>(std::vector<std::string>{ value });
```

Or using C++17 CTAD:

```cpp
auto values = std::make_unique<std::vector<std::string>>(std::vector{ value });
```

This will generalise to any number of fixed elements. If you just want a vector with three elements but don't care about the values, you can use `std::vector`'s "count" constructor:

```cpp
auto values = std::make_unique<std::vector<std::string>>(3);
// values contains three empty strings
```

Answer (score 0):

If `value` is a local variable, you can use the iterator constructor. Otherwise, you can directly use `new` to use the initialiser list constructor.

```cpp
using string_vec = std::vector<std::string>;

auto values = std::make_unique<string_vec>(&value, &value + 1);
auto values = std::unique_ptr<string_vec>(new string_vec{ value });
```

And of course the second way easily generalises to small fixed-size initializers, like `new string_vec{ value_1, value_2, value_3 }`. With the first way, you would have to store them in a `std::string[3]` and just pass the begin/end of that.